# Merging .dtsx files in SSIS

Tags: c#, git, merge, ssis

Situation: me and the other developer work on the same .dtsx package (in VS 2019) on two other git branches. We want to merge our changes to the master branch, but there's a pile of conflicts for whoever tries to merge second.

Is there any tool or way to merge this package without having to resolve every conflict by hand?

Comment: Have you ever opened a .dstx file in a text editor? not a chance. I suggest you refrain from having two developers work on the same package. SSIS packages should be so simple that there's no need for two devs in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already made the changes and aren't able to identify all the differences, one option would be to import your SSIS packages into the [BimlOnline](http://bimlonline.com/) tool from Varigence and then compare the resulting Biml Scripts that result.

As Nick commented however, dtsx files do *not* play well with multiple editors.  The xml of the file contains the logic, the properties and the *layout* of each package, so even moving a task one pixel will result in a change.

If shared development is a requirement for your environment however, I would strongly recommend learning how to use Biml via the BimlExpress Visual Studio add-on.  If you are able to develop your projects within a metadata driven Biml solution you can see significant reductions in time to deliver on adjustments and new features, as well as the ability to source control your Biml scripts rather than the dtsx files themselves.

That said, Nick is also right that your packages shouldn't be complex.  You almost always get better performance and more easily maintainale solutions by encapsulating all the ETL logic into stored procedures and relegating SSIS to simply calling the right procedure at the right time.

Comment: I am perfectly aware that our architecture isn't great at the moment, however business is business and refactoring it is not an option now. I was actually looking into biml scripts, they look very promising, however I see it has problems with Firebird databases connections - connection strings in biml generate a lot of problems of not supported keywords or not being able to connect at all.

Comment: Could you make your connections manually created project at the project level that are referenced, but not defined in the Biml?  That way you could output your packages into that project without the connection issues?

Comment: I see the problem is mainly that the biml tries to execute query on SQL server (I'm getting Named Pipes Provider, error: 40) while Firebird is not supported by it. I don't know if there's fix for that unfortunately. Strange thing is that in a .dtsx file I can setup an AdoNetConnection with Firebird provider and it works as it should be.

I've tried restarting the service and enabling pipes, it's still the same error

Comment: You can probably get around some of those problems by setting the Biml to not validate the SSIS package before outputting.

Comment: That could actually work out, is there a specific way I should go about this? I'm using BimlExpress right now.

Comment: When using most connections there is a setting for `DelayValidation`, as is the case with [AdoNetConnection](https://docs.varigence.com/biml-reference/language-reference/Varigence.Languages.Biml.Connection.AstAdoNetConnectionNode).  As a side note, the [language reference](https://docs.varigence.com/biml-reference/language-reference/Varigence.Languages.Biml.AstRootNode) available from Varigence is very complete and intuitive, which is a big help in putting scripts together.

Comment: DelayValidation won't work as it only delays validation, not turning it off completely. I think I will post that as a different question to not prolong the small answers here